# Why was the framerate so low in the first episode of Sidonia?

Tags: knights-of-sidonia

I only watched the first episode of Knights of Sidonia, and the main reason I dropped it was that the CG ran at an unbearably low framerate. I just took another look at it, and it looks like most of it past the opening sequence was ["on threes"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15567/1908).

I can understand why it's rare for anime to do hand-drawn animation (besides pans/etc) on ones - it takes a lot of work!

But I can't comprehend why this would happen with Sidonia - it was 100% CG! It seems like cranking the framerate up to twos or ones would just be a matter of changing a setting in whatever tool they were using to render the CG. Last year's "Aoki Hagane no Arpeggio" was full-CG too, and it didn't have this problem...

Do we know why the CG framerate was so low? Was it production issues, or an artistic choice, or...? (Side question: did it get better in later episodes and/or on the BD?)

Comment: Is that from a certain fansubs or the original BR release? Could be the problem with the converter if it is the first.

Comment: @SakuraiTomoki I am referring to the original TV airing. It is not possible that this is a downstream video conversion issue, since backgrounds and so forth still run at 24 fps just fine.

Comment: [A related discussion on Japanese Yahoo! Answer](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13128149893) (not posted as an answer since there's no official reason, also the FPS gets better since ep.3)